# Trying to run a count so I know when the last row of data is written so I can output a ']' instead of a ','

Tags: c++, if-statement, vector, count

I want my output file to look like this:

[image]

However, no matter what I try, it looks like this:

[image]

I can't get my comma condition to work for the output. I've tried to use eof, counts, etc but I'm not really sure where to go.

I've tried looking at other posts, but I either can't find one linked, or I don't actually understand it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> //ofstream declared in this header file
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//Creates Structure For Columns
struct InputFile
{
    string Date;
    string Value;
    string SignalStrength;
    string Voltage;
};

int main()
{
    ifstream input;
    string Row;
    string Column;
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;

    //Stores Data From Structure As Vector
    vector<InputFile> InputDataStored;
    input.open("Temperature.csv");

    if (input.fail())
    {
        cerr << "File does not exist. Exiting" << endl; //cerr is cout for errors
        return 1; //This could be used as an error code
    }

    if (!input)
    {
        cerr << "File could not be opened." << endl;
    }

    while (getline(input, Row))   //Remove top line output from sensor data when opened in Notepad
    {
        getline(input, Row);  // read an entire row and store it in a string variable 'line'
        stringstream ss{ Row };  // used for breaking words
        vector<string> Columns;  // creates a temporary vector of strings
        while (getline(ss, Column, ','))  // read an entire row and store it in a string variable 'column'
        {
            Columns.push_back(Column);  // add all the data of a row to the temporary vector
            count++;
        }
        //InputFile t{};  // convert string to struct types
        InputFile t;

        if (Row.empty())
            continue; //  if it is a blank row, ignore it
        else
        t.Date = Columns[1];
        t.Value = Columns[2];
        t.SignalStrength = Columns[4];
        t.Voltage = Columns[5];
        InputDataStored.push_back(t);  // add all the data of the new row to a vector
        count2++;
        cout << t.Date << "         " << t.Value << "         " << t.SignalStrength << "         " << t.Voltage << endl;
    }

    input.close();

    ofstream output;
    output.open("SensorData.json");

    if (!output)
    {
        cerr << "File could not be opened." << endl;
    }
    int JSONcount = 0;

    output << "[";

    for (InputFile t : InputDataStored)
    {

        JSONcount++;
        output << "{" << endl;
        output << "\"Date\": \"" << t.Date << "\"" << endl;
        output << "\"Temperature\": " << t.Value << endl;
        output << "\"Signal_strength\": " << t.SignalStrength << endl;
        output << "\"Voltage\": " << t.Voltage << endl;

        if (count2 >= JSONcount)
            output << "}]" << endl;
        else
            output << "}," << endl;      
    }

    output << JSONcount << endl;
    output << count << endl;
    output << count2;
    output.close();
}
```

Comment: Just like you output `[` before the loop, you could output `]` after the loop (with some `endl` adjustments). Likewise, you could output the `,` *before* each opening brace (except the first one). It is a lot easier to keep track of first output than guessing what is the last one.

Comment: @Kev9899 On a side note, you are calling `getline(input, Row)` twice per loop iteration of the input file, which seems wrong. Perhaps you meant to call `getline()` one time *before* entering the loop, and call `getline()` only one time per row?

Comment: This way would mean I have a random , on the last row of data, which I am also trying to avoid.

Comment: @Kev9899 no, you wouldn't.  Re-read what BoP said. You would output `[` first, then loop outputting `,` *before* each row except the 1st, then you would output `]` after the loop ends. No stray `,`s would be output.

Comment: Sorry yes I see what BoP means now. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes in your code.  Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct InputFile
{
    string Date;
    string Value;
    string SignalStrength;
    string Voltage;
};

int main()
{
    vector<InputFile> InputDataStored;
    string Line, Column;
    int count = 0, count2 = 0;

    ifstream input("Temperature.csv");
    if (!input)
    {
        cerr << "Input file could not be opened. Exiting" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    getline(input, Line);   //Remove top line output from sensor data when opened in Notepad

    while (getline(input, Line))  // read an entire row and store it in a string variable 'line'
    {
        istringstream iss{ Line };
        if (Line.empty())
            continue;

        vector<string> Columns;
        while (getline(iss, Column, ','))
        {
            Columns.push_back(Column);
            ++count;
        }

        InputFile t;
        t.Date = Columns[1];
        t.Value = Columns[2];
        t.SignalStrength = Columns[4];
        t.Voltage = Columns[5];

        InputDataStored.push_back(t);
        ++count2;

        cout << t.Date << "         " << t.Value << "         " << t.SignalStrength << "         " << t.Voltage << endl;
    }

    input.close();

    ofstream output("SensorData.json");
    if (!output)
    {
        cerr << "Output file could not be opened. Exiting" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int JSONcount = 0;

    output << "[";
    for (const auto &t : InputDataStored)
    {
        ++JSONcount;
        if (JSONcount > 1)
            output << "," << endl;

        output << "{" << endl;
        output << "\"Date\": \"" << t.Date << "\"" << endl;
        output << "\"Temperature\": " << t.Value << endl;
        output << "\"Signal_strength\": " << t.SignalStrength << endl;
        output << "\"Voltage\": " << t.Voltage << endl;
        output << "}";
    }
    output << "]" << endl;

    output << JSONcount << endl;
    output << count << endl;
    output << count2;

    output.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. Been hitting my head against a wall this evening. Really appreciate the replies.